# IntelliJ auto import dependencies failed with no details

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I opened a Maven project in IntelliJ. Then it automatically tries to import the dependencies, but all I saw was just a single line of error:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Transfer failed for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom ProxyInfo{host='aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd', userName='null', port=8080, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}
```

If I run Maven directly from the command prompt (mvn install), I can see all the details, including failures such as HTTP 503 (Service Unavailable).

How to make IntelliJ automatically download, and show me the exact errors? If it fails, how to make it retry the download?

Comment: It looks like you are going via a proxy which means the proxy has problems... (HTTP 503 (Service Unavailable))..

Comment: My point is, why is it that from the command prompt, I can see the exact details (HTTP 503), but within IntelliJ, there are no details at all? Does that mean that whenever I add a new dependency in pom.xml, I need to run Maven from the command line to import the dependency?

Comment: That can mean two things. your configuration in IDEA IntelliJ is not correct but in general you have a problem with your proxy which is the root problem...which should be solved first....

Comment: I added a <mirror> in settings.xml and I can now run maven build successfully from the command prompt. All the dependencies were downloaded. However, in IntelliJ, I am still getting "unresolved" symbols, with the third party packages and classes highlighted in red. I did an "Invalidate Caches / Restart", but the errors won't go away. I also run "maven clean" and "maven compile" inside IntelliJ and they were successful as I can see the compiled class in the target folder.